# reload rails.root/app/resources/* per request

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, reload, rack

I have a rails app with a folder `rails.root/app/resources` where I keep some library code.
This library code is used in a *rack app* that I mount in `routes.rb` in my Rails application

```
# rails.root/app/resources/file_resource.rb

# routes.rb
mount DAV4Rack::Handler.new(
  :root => Rails.root.to_s,
  :resource_class => FileResource
), :at => '/', :constraints => {:subdomain => "w"}
```

How can I make the FileResource reload on each request in development?

I tried `autoload_paths`, `reload_plugin`, none seem to work.

I think it has something to do with the code in routes.rb.
If I make a file `rails.root/app/resources/my_helper.rb` and use MyHelper.test() inside FileResource, the MyHelper gets reloaded.

No, I don't want to move this in 'lib' folder.

Comment: Why don't you want to move it into 'lib'?

Comment: I enjoy the aesthetics of having it in app, since it's not generic library code, it's application-specific logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently using the following hack, if anyone has a better solution please do share!

```
# config/environments/development.rb
root = config.root
config.to_prepare do
  load "#{root}/app/resources/file_resource.rb"
end
```